# Project A's application.yml was not loaded in project B that has a dependency on A

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have two spring boot projects A and B. Project A is a common library built into a jar; project B is a web services packaged into a war. Project B has a dependency on A in pom.xml.

In project A:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ComponentScan({ "com.a" })
public class AppA {

}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="a")
@Data
public class AConfig {
    private String attr1;  //in application.yml under project A's classpath
}
```

In project A the following test passed:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AppA.class)
public class SDTTokenServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private AConfig aConfig;

    @Test
    public void testAConfig () {
        Assert.assertNotNull(aConfig.getAtrr1());
    }
}
```

In project B:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(AppA.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ComponentScan({ "com.b" })
public class AppB {

}
```

In project B, the following test failed due to the null property.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AppB.class)
public class SDTTokenServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private AConfig aConfig;

    @Test
    public void testAConfig () {
        Assert.assertNotNull(aConfig.getAtrr1());
    }
}
```

Why project B cannot get the properties in A? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Update:
Both yaml files are under their classpath, maybe that creates the conflict when import project A in project B. After I moved the yaml file in project A to a different path `classpath:config/application.yml` then it works correctly.

Does anyone know how the yaml files are loaded under this situation? Why it doesn't work when they are all under their own classpath? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of annotating `AppA` with `@PropertySource`, you should add location in `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="a", location={"classpath:application.yml"})
@Data
public class AConfig {
    private String attr1;  //in application.yml under project A's classpath
}
```

`@Import` annotation is used to import `@Configuration`, not `@SpringBootApplication`.

> Indicates one or more {@link Configuration @Configuration} classes to import.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(AConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ComponentScan({ "com.b" })
public class AppB {

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your method, it still doesn't work. I thought it might be the file path and name conflicts between these two projects that B cannot load the config in A. After I move the yaml file path in A to `classpath:config/application.yml` then it works correctly.